# Why does Latex swallow the whitespace after \LaTeX command?

Tags: spacing

The sentence

> LaTeX is fun

is produced by

```
\LaTeX\ is fun
```

Why does Latex tend to swallow the space between the words 'Latex' and 'is' unless the space is escaped by a backslash?

Comment: A very common question :-) It's a dupe, I'm afraid.

Comment: TeX gobbles up any whitespace after a "control sequence" or command like `\LaTeX`.